# What is Batman's height? And Superman's?

Tags: dc, batman, superman

I couldn't find a definitive reference about that. In the comics they seem to have about the same height.

Anyone knows?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How heavy is Superman on Earth?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28794/how-heavy-is-superman-on-earth)

Comment: This question, while possibly close-worthy, is not deserving of downvotes IMO

Comment: I can't believe they downvote my question! Why is this? Because it was already answered before? FYI, I've made a search in the site before asking the question using keywords like 'batman', 'height', 'tall' and haven't found the answer... How can I know that a question with the title 'How heavy is Superman on Earth?' would have an answer to my question?

Comment: Anyone knows about Wonder Woman's height in DCAU?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Batman is 6'2" and Superman is 6'3" according to [dc.wikia.com](http://dc.wikia.com/).

Comment: That seems awefully tall for Batman to be as acrobatic and agile as he is usually depicted.  I always pictured him being somewhere aroung 5'10"-5'11" with Dick Grayson being roughly 5'7"-5'8".  Superman's height seems likely though.

Comment: @Monty129: That's a good point about gymnasts and acrobats. However, there are still professional gymnasts as well as acrobats in the 6'0"~6'3" range. These include Vegas acrobats and NCAA Division I and Olympic gymnasts.

Batman would be at a competitive disadvantage when it comes to competing in gymnastics or being a circus acrobat, but it's still possible to overcome those disadvantages, and he's not really an acrobat or gymnast. He would likely gain more from greater height and weight than he would from being small.

Comment: Specifically, being larger confers more absolute strength, reach, leap, ability to take abuse, as well as the intimidation factor.

In comparison, relative strength isn't as useful to a crime-fighter who doesn't travel by monkeybars or web slinging. A slightly higher or lower center of mass wouldn't affect his balance enough to really matter. And less rotational inertia isn't a huge benefit when you're not doing flips and spins and are just fighting and chasing criminals over rooftops.

Comment: I think is much more important for Batman to be big and massive than being small and agile, when you fight with other people, it's VERY important to be big and strong in close combat situations, specially when fighting with multiple opponents

Answer (score 2):

Batman is 6'2" probably around 230lbs ripped in the comics
Superman is 6'3" 235lbs ripped in the comics

They're pretty much bodybuilders

Comment: Can you add a reference?

Comment: Also their physiques would be more akin to MMA fighters than bodybuilders.  Bodybuilding is more about form over function, specifically definition.  The most striated muscles are not necessarily the strongest.

Answer (score 1):

I remember reading in a question to the comics (when some of theses were actually answered) ... I think it was around 1959 or 1960.  The question was about Superman but the answer came back as Supes was 6' 2" tall and weighed 235#. The Bats was 6' 4" and 245#. Most readers here weren't even a thought in their parents dreams then but I am absolutely certain of that response because I thought it was so interesting and I had a near photographic memory in my youth.

Answer (score 0):

I remember back in the 90's, when they were discussing one of the Tim Burton sequels, I went to a baseball game and Jose Canseco was playing. He was listed as 6'4" and 220 pounds. At the time, that was the exact listed height and weight for Bruce Wayne in the DC universe. I got rid of my collection from back then, so I can't find an official confirmation of those stats.